# Synchronizing database from CSV files

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, csv, sql-server-2008-r2

I need ideas for a problem I am working on:

I am writing a data synchronizer in C#.Net that will receive CSV files, one for each table in a SQL Server database.

Some of the rows in the csv files will reference existing rows in the database, requiring an update, and some will reference new rows, requiring an insert.

Since there might be a lot of files (20 or so) and potentially a lot of rows in each, how can I make this scalable? Reading one row at the time, connecting to the database to make sure if a row with that same ID exists or not (to make sure if it is an update or insert) and then making another connection for doing the actual update or insert seems wasteful.

Comment: What amount of data are we talking about? I am trying to determine if you are being premature when talking about scale.

Comment: I'd be tempted to divide this up and try and do things in bulk, look for say 500 of the rows in the existing database at one time. Then map them back in code then do the updates/inserts together (no reason you can't reuse the same connection). When working with this much data it's worth thinking what you'll do if it fails, transactions are worth considering

Comment: You should read up on [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) - that's what's it for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Load everything in a temporary table (bulk insert)
2. Perform a merge update to the target table.

Comment: A viable approach - simple and efficient! Provided you don't have any constraints on the SQL side (ie. you can modify the existing schema, can handle the extra tables, don't mind writing T-SQL).

Comment: You do not need to add any index. It will only slow down total processing time. If SQL Server needs the input sorted, it can sort it on the fly (because the merge source table will only be read once).

Comment: @usr: You're right. The key lookup will be the other way around, so indexes are not needed. Have removed the step from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [SQL Server Integration Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) for this kind of work.

> SSIS is a platform for data integration and workflow applications. It features a fast and flexible data warehousing tool used for data extraction, transformation, and loading (ETL).

Answer (score 0):

Also a good source to use as reference could be [CsvReader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx%20%22CsvReader)

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to use SSIS .In SSIS we have csv reader component (Flat File Source) which handles all type of flat files ( pipeline or tab delimited. etc )  .Using Lookup u can check with the existing row in the table and then u can either update , insert or delete using Oledb Component .

If you don't want to use SSIS there is a other way round using XML Stored Procedure .Instead of hitting the database for every row u can pass the data as an XML and then manipulate in the Stored Procedure .

Example : To insert data into table using XML as a source

```
            CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Insert_XML]
        @XMLDATA xml
```

AS

BEGIN

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Insert statements for procedure here
Insert into RCMReport(
   ProjectName
  ,Category
  ,EndTime)
    Select  
        XMLDATA.item.value('@ProjectName[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS ProjectName,   
        XMLDATA.item.value('@Category[1]', 'varchar(200)') AS Category,
        XMLDATA.item.value('@EndTime[1]', 'datetime') AS EndTime
            FROM @XMLDATA.nodes('//RCMReport/InsertList') AS XMLDATA(item)
```